# Knitr: the tex characters are lost when the HTML is removed from the original directory

Tags: html, r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I am using Knitr and RMarkdown in RStudio on a cluster and the HTML output I am producing has some Latex expressions and equations. However when I am moving the file from the cluster to my personal laptop, the Latex expressions are lost and only the Latex syntax is displayed. Is there a way to retain the Latex characters and environments even when the HTML file is not in the same environment as the .RmD file?

Thanks a lot